# How to use res.render data as a $scope object in angular controller ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a route defined in node/express that has a res.render

```
router.get('/',
    function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {user: req.user});
    });
```

On rendering this index page, I want to capture this req.user as a $scope object in the angular controller on the front end. How can this be done?

Please provide code snippets with the answer.

Comment: Afaik, there is no good way to do it. Though you can stringify `user` and render it to inline script of html template or a hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you first need to add a line in JADE to create a global javascript object that will hold the user value, i.e.

```
script(text/javascript).
  var theUSER = !{JSON.stringify(user)}; // inserted by jade
```

Now in your controller just do this

```
app.controller('AnyController',function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.user = theUSER; 
});
```

I have done this for a few projects.

Aaron